# $_POST - пустой массив, $_GET - работает нормально

Tags: php, post, get

При помощи приложения Postman проверяю следующий код:

```
<?php
    require "../db.php";
    //var_dump($_POST);

    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $user = R::findOne('users', 'login = ?', array($login));
    if($user)
    {
        if(password_verify($password, $user->password))
        {
            echo 'Вы успешно авторизованы';
        }
        else { $errors[] = 'Неверно введён пароль!'; }
    }
    else { $errors[] = 'Пользователь с таким логином не найден: '.$login; }

    if(!empty($errors))
    {
        foreach($errors AS $error)
        {
            echo $error;
        }
    }
?>
```

Файл db.php:

```
<?php
    require "libs/rb.php";
    R::setup( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=authorizationdb','root', '' );

    session_start();
?>
```

rb.php это библиотека RedBean для удобного управления БД. Её можно скачать отсюда:

https://redbeanphp.com/downloadredbean.php

Когда я в Postman'е пытаюсь отправить запрос POST с логином и паролем, переменная $_POST оказывается пустым массивом, при этом, когда я меняю в Postman'е POST на GET, и в коде соответственно все переменные $_POST на $_GET, массив $_GET оказывается непустым, и код работает правильно. Что нужно сделать, чтобы в $_POST откладывались логин и пароль, отправленные с запросом?

Comment: А вы не пробовали создать статическую страницу с формой для POST и для GET запросов, да проверить всё ли нормально у вас со стороны клиента? Я к тому, что вы уверены что ваше приложение корректно отсылает POST запрос? Нужно же определиться где проблема.

Comment: @Rootware вот что со стороны клиента

https://vk.com/id27696843?z=photo27696843_456239457%2Falbum27696843_00%2Frev

Comment: @Rootware я сначала делал это в виде формы, всё работало. Но мне нужно, чтобы это был запрос и JSON-ответ, т.к. я собираюсь подключать к серверу мобильное приложение

Comment: @Jean-Claude то же пустой массив. а с $_GET всё работает. но мне не рекомендовали использовать при авторизации запрос GET, чтобы не было возможности прописывать запрос в строке, т.е. в целях безопасности

Comment: @Jean-Claude application/x-www-form-urlencoded результата не дал. а https://client.restlet.com/ годится ли для проверки локальных сайтов?

Comment: @Jean-Claude по ходу с локальными серверами не работает. попробовал ввести - выдаёт Unknown host

Comment: естественно, в общем, дружок, у тебя бяка где-то, отключи все левые библиотеки для проверки, у меня все работает https://imgur.com/a/k3F2Gud мало ли RedBean чё творит с POST...

Comment: @Jean-Claude, но в форме ввода логина и пароля тоже POST, и тоже библиотека RedBean обрабатывает - и всё проходит нормально, а других библиотек не подключено